# Capture and edit response from callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mailchimp

I'm using [AjaxChimp](https://github.com/scdoshi/jquery-ajaxchimp) to use ajax to submit a sign up form to MailChimp.

The issue I have is that I'm using a callback function as in this example here: [AJAX Mailchimp signup form integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425701/ajax-mailchimp-signup-form-integration/23945648#23945648)

but I would like to trap and modify the response text I get back from MailChimp. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('form').ajaxChimp({
                callback: function(response) {
                    $('form .result').text(response.msg);                      
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Any help in how to do this is very much appreciated. I'm a javascript beginner.

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Does response.msg get added as text to the 'form .result' element?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what happens.

Comment: So the below answers should work. Did they work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to modify the response text?  Here is an example of concatentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('form').ajaxChimp({
                callback: function(response) {
                    var modifiedText = "The response was " + response.msg;
                    $('form .result').text(modifiedText);
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

There are many other ways to modify a string.  Here are some examples:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('form').ajaxChimp({
                callback: function(response) {
                    // u can this change response like
                    response = response + ' foo ' ;
                    $('form .result').text(response.msg);                      
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```