# Custom mailchimp signup form in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, mailchimp, newsletter

I have a react app that I would like to add mailchimp signup form to. I am building a custom signup form and have user sign up by entering their first and last name and email. I am not dealing with any campaign stuff. All I am trying to achieve is that once they sign up, they get an email to confirm subscription.

I have done what's in the mailchimp guide http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/host-your-own-signup-forms but it's always giving me error 500.

Here's the code for the send event

```
subscribe(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  axios({
    url: 'https://xxxxxx.us15.list-manage.com/subscribe/post',
    method: 'post',
    data: this.state,
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('success');
  });
}
```

and here's the form

```
<form onSubmit={this.subscribe.bind(this)}>
  <input type="hidden" name="u" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />

  <label>First Name</label>
  <input name="FNAME" type="text" onChange={this.handler.bind(this, 'FNAME')} required="true"/>

  <label>Last Name</label>
  <input name="LNAME" type="text" onChange={this.handler.bind(this, 'LNAME')} required="true"/>

  <label>Email</label>
  <input name="EMAIL" type="email" onChange={this.handler.bind(this, 'EMAIL')} required="true"/>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

I have also tried the suggestion in this link [AJAX Mailchimp signup form integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425701/ajax-mailchimp-signup-form-integration)

basically passing the u and id along with the url instead of input in the form. but that didn't work either.

Anyone has idea on how to make this work? Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think this is possible using the example code Mailchimp provides for a custom sign up form with React. You would need to use the Mailchimp API instead, but have your own server handle the request as they do not enable CORS, so an API request won't work from the client.

Answer (score 38):

It is possible. [1]

As you mentioned in your [link](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/host-your-own-signup-forms), MailChimp allows you to post the values of form elements on our client to subscribe people to your mailing list. Anything more advanced than that, and you need to use their API, thus requiring CORS (i.e. the API can't be utilized by the client).

If you aren't using React – you can simply copy/paste MailChimp's embedded form builder. But if you are in React, here's what you can do:

1) **Get the `u` and `id` value**

This is outlined in the link above. Or, You can go into your form builder and find the action field: it will be something like `https://cool.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=eb05e4f830c2a04be30171b01&amp;id=8281a64779` where `u` and `id` are in the query arguments.

2) **Add `onChange` and `value` attributes to form elements**

If you just have some simple form elements, you'll notice that typing doesn't do anything. Typing doesn't render any text inside the input elements. Read https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html to understand why. (React needs a single source of truth for state).

The value needs to be updated. You can do this by updating state in a function that's bind'd.

```
<input 
  value={this.state.emailValue} 
  onChange={ (e)=>{this.setState({emailValue: e.target.value});} } 
/>
```

3) **Bonus: include MailChimp's antispam fields**

If you read the code inside the embedded forms, you'll notice things like:

```
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_eb05e4f830c2a04be30171b01_8281a64779" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
```

You can include these in React by changing the appropriate fields for Babel and JSX. `class` needs to be `className`. the `<input>` tag needs to be closed, and style needs to be passed as an object.

In sum: here's an entire component

```
import React from 'react'

class SubscribePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        emailValue: '',
        fNameValue: '',
        lNameValue: '',
    };
  }

    render() {
        return (
                <form action="https://cool.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="POST" noValidate>
                  <input type="hidden" name="u" value="eb05e4f830c2a04be30171b01"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="8281a64779"/>
                <label htmlFor='MERGE0'>
                    Email
                    <input 
                        type="email" 
                        name="EMAIL" 
                        id="MERGE0"
                        value={this.state.emailValue} 
                        onChange={ (e)=>{this.setState({emailValue: e.target.value});} } 
                        autoCapitalize="off" 
                        autoCorrect="off"
                     /> 
                </label>
                <label htmlFor='MERGE1'>
                    First name
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="FNAME" 
                        id="MERGE1" 
                        value={this.state.fNameValue} 
                        onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({fNameValue: e.target.value});}}
                    />
                </label>
                <label htmlFor='MERGE2'>
                    Last name
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="LNAME" 
                        id="MERGE2" 
                        value={this.state.lNameValue} 
                        onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({lNameValue: e.target.value});}}
                    />
                </label>
                  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" className="button"/>

                <div style={{position: 'absolute', left: '-5000px'}} aria-hidden='true' aria-label="Please leave the following three fields empty">
                    <label htmlFor="b_name">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="b_name" tabIndex="-1" value="" placeholder="Freddie" id="b_name"/>

                    <label htmlFor="b_email">Email: </label>
                    <input type="email" name="b_email" tabIndex="-1" value="" placeholder="youremail@gmail.com" id="b_email"/>

                    <label htmlFor="b_comment">Comment: </label>
                    <textarea name="b_comment" tabIndex="-1" placeholder="Please comment" id="b_comment"></textarea>
                </div>
              </form>
        )
    }
}

export default SubscribePage
```

[1]: Note that the user will be taken to a MailChimp page, and asked to verify the subscription by clicking on a link in their email. To avoid this, you gotta use the API

Comment: Thanks for the example. When I run this I get the Warning: Unknown prop `forHtml` on <label> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html

Comment: It's supposed to be htmlFor. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Nov 2019 and this still works. Thank you for posting all the code, and the steps, it made it so much easier to follow!

Comment: doesnt work anymore, it goes to a page saying "That's odd This page appears to be missing."

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a lot of issues trying to get the form to work in React and not open a confirmation page.

There are a few ways to get around this, the easiest method is to use the [react-mailchimp-subscribe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mailchimp-subscribe) package. This is super strait forward and the package is fairly light. The only thing needed to get this form to work is the action URL that Mailchimp provides you on the Embed Form page for your list.

If you don't want to use the package, you can dive into the source and recreate what is being done very simply. The few things that have to be changed are the URL from

`http://xxxxx.us#.list.com/subscribe/post?u=xxxxx&id=xxxx`

to

`http://xxxxx.us#.list.com/subscribe/post-json?u=xxxxx&id=xxxx`

In addition to adding the `-json`, you will need to add param `c` that is blank (this can be done in the jsonp request or added to the url by adding `&c=?`).

With this implementation you should no longer get redirected and all messages will come back in JSON format. Also note that you do not need to have their script tag on your page for this to work.

References:

1. [AJAX Mailchimp signup form integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425701/ajax-mailchimp-signup-form-integration)

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for a ready to use React solution (credit to @adriendenat in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611587/8793935) answer):

```
import jsonp from 'jsonp';
import queryString from 'query-string';

// ...

const subscribeToNewsLetter = () => {
  const formData = {
    EMAIL: // your email string,
  };
  jsonp(`YOUR_URL/subscribe/post-json?u=YOUR_U&amp;id=YOUR_ID&${queryString.stringify(formData)}`, { param: 'c' }, (err, data) => {
    console.log('err:', err);
    console.log('data:', data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @marco-gaspari, I also ran into a lot of issues with this. My answer is a variation of theirs, but with some tweaks that, for me, were necessary to make it work.

In addition to switching `post`at the end of the `action` url to `post-json` and including the `c` attribute equal to `?` (in addition to the `u` and `id` attributes from the original url; all of which I chose to incorporate as `hidden` input fields), I also had to redirect the output to a hidden `<iframe>`. Otherwise, a new page opened with the json response.

This may have been due to my using a custom form; but for others also using [custom Mailchimp signup forms](https://mailchimp.com/help/host-your-own-signup-forms/), this solution may be helpful.

```html
<form action="https://xxx.usxx.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json" method="post" className="validate" target="hiddenFrame" >
       <!--u and id values from url generated by Mailchimp form builder -->
       <input type="hidden" name="u" value="xxxxxxxx" />
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="xxxxxxx" />
       <input type="hidden" name="c" value="?" />
 </form>
    <iframe name="hiddenFrame" src="about:blank" style={{display:'none'}}></iframe>
```