# Mailchimp in a single page app - API key made public?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

My single page app has no backend per se (firebase) and now needs to interface with Mailchimp to allow visitors to register to the newsletter.

So far, I have this API key - it seems to give full access to my mailchimp account.
Can one simply call the Mailchimp api from an SPA to register, without providing an api key?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the API key gives access to your account and should therefore be kept private. There isn't a way to use the MailChimp API without providing an API key, but if you are only using it to subscribe users, you can do this through a simple AJAX call instead. This method uses a User ID instead of a private API key to identify your account.

The request below is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120409/7191168):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://xxxxx.us#.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=xxxxx&id=xxxx&c=?',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    cache       : false,
    dataType    : 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    error       : function(err) { alert("Could not connect to the registration server. Please try again later."); },
    success     : function(data) {
        if (data.result != "success") {
            //Failed
        } else {
            //Success
        }
    }
});
```

To find the values that need to be placed in the `url` string, follow the instructions on [this page from MailChimp's knowledgebase](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/host-your-own-signup-forms). You'll need your username, the correct `us#` server, the `u` value (which is the User ID previously described), and the `id` value (which is the list ID).

Comment: Thank, really helpful!