# Handle Mailchimp signup form with AJAX and vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mailchimp

I have an embedded Mailchimp signup form which I want to process via AJAX. I've followed the top answer from this question ([AJAX Mailchimp signup form integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425701/ajax-mailchimp-signup-form-integration)) to make edits to the HTML form markup, however I don't use jQuery in my project so I tried to make it work with vanilla JavaScript:

```
<form action="https://gmail.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=XXX0&amp;id=XXX&amp;c=?" method="get" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>...</form>
```

```
const form = document.querySelector('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  fetch(e.target.action, {
    method: e.target.method,
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

which results in the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

The jQuery solution works just OK though. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the extra coma after the `headers` closing bracket.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that.

Answer (score 0):

The [action url](https://gmail.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post-json?u=XXX0&id=XXX&c=?) results in 404.

Therefore, this is the `response.json();` that throws the *Unexpected end of input*.

To avoid the *Uncaught* error, catch it using a `catch()` block after the last `then()`.

```
let form = document.querySelector("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  fetch(e.target.action, {
    method: e.target.method,
    mode: "no-cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Request failed.");  // Custom message on the error to throw
      } else {
        return response.json();  // Call .json() only on good responses
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("data: " + data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {  // Catch the error here
      console.log("error: "+error);
    });
});
```